# Linq query to group by based on special condition

Tags: c#, .net, linq

**My table is:**

```
id | globalId | taskStatus |
1  | 10       | New        | 
2  | 11       | New        |
3  | 10       | InProgress |
4  | 12       | New        |
```

I would like to have a linq query that returns me result with row 2.

Conditions to check in query

1. Want to ignore those records which have same globalId and if task status of any record is InProgress. So in this case as record with 1, 3 have same global id 10 but task status of record with id 3 is InProgress, so don't want any of the two records.
2. Also a check in where condition Id < 4

I have tried the below query

```
  var result = (from meetings in db.Meetings
                      join taskStatus in db.TaskStatus on meeting.TaskStatusId equals taskStatus.TaskStatusId
                      where (taskStatus.Name == InternalTaskStatus.New || taskStatus.Name == InternalTaskStatus.ToBePlannedInFuture || taskStatus.Name == InternalTaskStatus.Failed)
                      && meeting.CalendarEvent != CalendarEvents.Delete
                      && meeting.StartDateTime >= planningPeriodStartDate && meeting.EndDateTime <= planningPeriodEndDate
                      group meeting by meeting.GlobalAppointmentId  into m
                      select new
                      {
                          MeetingResult = m.FirstOrDefault()
                      }).FirstOrDefault();
```

In the above query I have added check for task status, want only records with taskStatus-New,Failed,ToBePlannedInFuture. But here I am getting wrong result in this case as per above table I am getting result with id 1.

Comment: @HimBromBeere  please check the query which I have tried

Answer (score 1):

The ideal way to approach this is to, split the requirement.

Requirement 1 : Ignore Items where id < 4

```
var step1 = testList.Where(x=>x.id<4);
```

[image]

Requirement 2: Ignore Groups of items with same globalId is same, and none of the elements in group has status in "InProgress"

```
var step2 = step1.GroupBy(x=>x.globalId)
            .Where(x=>!x.Any(c=>c.taskStatus.Equals("InProgress")));
```

[image]

Now you need to flatten the group to get the result as IEnumerabble

```
var step3= step2.SelectMany(x=>x);
```

[image]

Putting it all together

```
var result = testList.Where(x=>x.id<4).GroupBy(x=>x.globalId)
            .Where(x=>!x.Any(c=>c.taskStatus.Equals("InProgress")))
            .SelectMany(x=>x);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class test
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public int globalId { get; set; }
        public string taskStatus { get; set; }
    }

    public void SampleName()
    {
        List<test> testList = new List<test>()
        {
            new test() { id = 1, globalId =  10, taskStatus =  "New"},
            new test() { id = 2 , globalId = 11 , taskStatus = "New"},
            new test() { id = 3 , globalId = 10 , taskStatus = "InProgress"},
            new test() { id = 4 , globalId = 12 , taskStatus = "New"}
        };

        var result = testList.Where(q => testList.Count(a => a.globalId == q.globalId) == 1 && q.taskStatus != "InProgress" && q.id < 4).ToList();
    }
```

Comment: Code dumps generally make for poor answers.